# Email sending from android application

Tags: android

I am trying to send Email from my android app from background.Mail was sent successfully with attachment but still after that i am getting error in log.Here is the log please guide me where is the error and how to resolve it.

```
03-14 13:37:37.697: E/MailApp(1296): Could not send email
03-14 13:37:37.697: E/MailApp(1296): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
03-14 13:37:37.697: E/MailApp(1296):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
03-14 13:37:37.697: E/MailApp(1296):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
03-14 13:37:37.697: E/MailApp(1296):    at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:324)
03-14 13:37:37.697: E/MailApp(1296):    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
03-14 13:37:37.697: E/MailApp(1296):    at  android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
03-14 13:37:37.697: E/MailApp(1296):    at com.example.mytest.ReadContactsActivity.SendMail(ReadContactsActivity.java:173)
03-14 13:37:37.697: E/MailApp(1296):    at com.example.mytest.ReadContactsActivity.access$0(ReadContactsActivity.java:156)
03-14 13:37:37.697: E/MailApp(1296):    at com.example.mytest.ReadContactsActivity$CountDownTask.doInBackground(ReadContactsActivity.java:131)
03-14 13:37:37.697: E/MailApp(1296):    at com.example.mytest.ReadContactsActivity$CountDownTask.doInBackground(ReadContactsActivity.java:1)
03-14 13:37:37.697: E/MailApp(1296):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-14 13:37:37.697: E/MailApp(1296):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-14 13:37:37.697: E/MailApp(1296):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-14 13:37:37.697: E/MailApp(1296):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-14 13:37:37.697: E/MailApp(1296):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
```

Comment: I think you have to use AsyncTask... Post your code..

Comment: Can you please post your code ? If i am not wrong you are toast a message in thread .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to display `Toast` message inside the `AsynTask` `doInBackground()` method,
just do it in `onPostExecute()` method....

Answer (score 0):

You might be using some background thread which is directly trying to make change in your main thread, if that is the issue then use

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    //do your work here
  }
});
```